# Animation stuttering in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

The problem seems to be related only with Internet Explorer.
When the example is run with jsfiddle in IE, it runs smooth.
If tried on my local machine and opened with IE, it stutters.
What could the problem be?

UPDATE: If setTimeout is removed, it does not stutter, but if I force it to 60 frames by adding the setTimeout, it does.
I need to force it to 60 frames/sec and at least run smooth.

[The code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o3qbesy6/5/)

```
// Check if canvas exists and get the context of the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Add width and height of the canvas
var width = 640, height = 480;

// Make the canvas width and height as the variables
canvas.width = width, canvas.height = height;

rect = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 100
}

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);

function animate(){
setTimeout(function(){
    rect.x += 5;

    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height );
    ctx.fillRect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);

    if(rect.x <= 200){
        requestID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
}, 1000 / 60);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

Comment: I tried it on a virtual machine with IE11, it works fine, no stuttering

Comment: I forgot to add the setTimeout, which makes it exactly 60 frames/sec. Try it now, it stutters. If I remove the setTimeout, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to combine `requestAnimationFrame` and `setTimeout` for painting. Maybe you want to update your animation at a stable rate of 60 fps, but that doesn't mean you need to repaint at exactly 60 fps.

Separate animation update from animation paint and your problem will be solved:

```
function paintAnimation() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    requestAnimationFrame(paintAnimation);
}
requestAnimationFrame(paintAnimation);

function updateAnimation() {
    rect.x += 5;
    if (rect.x <= 200)
        setTimeout(updateAnimation, 1000 / 60);
}
updateAnimation();
```

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bm4vurus/)

Comment: How comes that in jsfiddle though it runs just fine with my example?